# Change notification support for outlookTask using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Does micorsoft graph API support change notification support for **outlookTask**, We have gone through documentation available at [webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0) but it does not contain any information specific to outlookTask. Basically we need resource name which can be used while creating subscription request for change notification. We already have created change notification and receiving them for **messages** and **meeting** resources.

Appreciate if anyone can guide or provide any information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Today change notifications (aka webhooks) do not support any kind of task (planner, Todo, Outlook). You can upvote the feature request here to help prioritize the work and be notified when progress is made.

https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/36249499-provide-webhooks-for-tasks-ms-to-do